# How to use AD B2C Automation to get a Token with custom claims

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using the techniques described in [AD B2C->Automation->Account Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet?tabs=applications) to get an Access token for an application. This is working fine, but I want to add some custom claims to the returned token. Is there some way I can use Custom Policies to add custom claims when an application requests a token?

Note: I already have custom policies that I use for interactive signons, which add claims to the returned token. I would like to somehow use these in a non-interactive mode.

Comment: How did you add custom claims to access token? In B2C custom claims should be included in JWT rather than access token. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom#add-the-claim.

Comment: Do you mean for client_credentials flow where the App is sending clientid and client secret to get a token? If so, what claims would you want on the app token? Or non-interactive ROPC flow for a user?

Comment: Currently I am using Custom Policies where the user signs in and then a JWT Token is returned with extra claims inserted by the policy. (The claims come from a call to a in house app). I want to automate this by having a app that authenticates with B2C (using Tenant Id and secret), then somehow gets a JWT for a user that has the extra claims.

Answer (score 0):

> I already have custom policies... I would like to somehow use these in a non-interactive mode.

For non-interactive authentication/authorization w/ B2C that would the [ROPC (Resource Owner Password Credentials)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom?tabs=applications) flow.

In the [relying party file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom?tabs=applications#create-a-relying-party-file) you can output [custom claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom):

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myCustomClaim" DefaultValue="" />
```